# Does my docker-machine AWS EC2 instances show up on docker-cloud web API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker, docker-machine, docker-cloud

I am a little confused with all the different offerings by docker.

So far, I have been using Docker Cloud Web API (cloud.docker.com) to create node-clusters on EC2 instances by linking to my AWS account.

Now recently, I wanted to setup a data container and mount is as a volume, that is shared by other containers running on the same node. This requires use of the **--volumes-from** flag in docker, which means I need to use docker-machine, connect to my AWS VM, and then launch my containers with this flag.

Do all of these containers show up on cloud.docker.com? Even the ones I launched from the terminal using docker-machine? Maybe I am confused here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that cloud.docker.com is still in Beta mode and so doesn't offer a --volumes-from. Also, these containers don't show on cloud.docker.com yet. Maybe it will come in the future...